# TagHelpers doesn't get invoked after moving them to a different project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm having some issues with asp.net core not finding and invoking my tag helpers. After I moved the taghelpers from a seperate assembly (*LC.Tools.Utility.TagHelpers*) to *LC.Tools.Utility* it doesnt seem like they get discovered even though the namespace is the same as before.

**Sample cshtml**:

```
<lc:css src="styles.min.css" />
<lc:css src="styles.bootstrap.min.css" />
<lc:css src="styles._layout.min.css" />
```

When looking at the source for the page the tags are exactly the same.

**_ViewImports.cshtml**:

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers 
@addTagHelper *, LC.Smokers.Albino.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, LC.Tools.Utility.TagHelpers
```

**LC.Tools.Utility.TagHelpers.IncludeCssTagHelper.cs** (*in assembly LC.Tools.Utility*):

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers;

namespace LC.Tools.Utility.TagHelpers
{
    [HtmlTargetElement("lc:css", Attributes = "src", TagStructure = TagStructure.WithoutEndTag)]
    public class IncludeCssTagHelper : Base
    {
        public IncludeCssTagHelper(IHostingEnvironment env) : base(env) { }

        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            output.TagName = "link";
            output.TagMode = TagMode.SelfClosing;

            bool isDebug = this.Environment.IsDevelopment() && this.DebugSrc.Length > 0;
            string path = "/CSS/";

            if (isDebug)
            {
                path += this.DebugSrc;

                if (Utility.IsUrl(this.DebugSrc))
                {
                    path = this.DebugSrc;
                }
            }
            else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Src))
            {
                path += this.Src;

                if (Utility.IsUrl(this.Src))
                {
                    path = this.Src;
                }
            }

            output.Attributes.Clear();

            output.Attributes.SetAttribute("href", path.ToLower());
            output.Attributes.SetAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
            output.Attributes.SetAttribute("type", "text/css");

            base.Process(context, output);
        }

        [HtmlAttributeName("src")]
        public string Src { get; set; }

        [HtmlAttributeName("debug-src")]
        public string DebugSrc { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

> I've tried deleting the bin and obj folders from all the projects and
>   rebuild the entire solution and removed and added reference to the
>   project.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `addTagHelper` directive expects two comma-separated parameters. The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro#managing-tag-helper-scope) has this to say about how it works:

> The first parameter after @addTagHelper specifies the Tag Helpers to load (we are using "*" for all Tag Helpers), and the second parameter "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers" specifies the **assembly** containing the Tag Helpers.

Note what I've highlighted in bold: It's not the namespace that is needed; it's the assembly. In your example, you need to change that second parameter to reflect the new hosting assembly:

```
@addTagHelper *, LC.Tools.Utility
```

Comment: Completely not helpful... My tag helper still isn't invoked... Of course it was naive of me to think I'd actually find useful information here that would be of any assistance whatsoever... Should've known better... `@addTagHelper *, ECShared.TagHelpers` and in ECShared.TagHelpers I have `MemberHistorySearchTagHelper`... so not doing anything wrong but still doesn't work... go figure.